# Getting error "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException" with FirebaseDatabase app

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I was following a tutorial online on how to create an android chat app with Xamarin that was implemented in Visual Studio 2015 and I was using Visual Studio 2017. I also tried to InitializeApp to see if that would fix it, but it did not work. What could be the problem? There was a couple of changes that I implemented, but I have one problem. I am getting an error "Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: " on line `FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("chats").AddValueEventListener(this);`

This is how I implented the OnCreate method:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this);

        firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);
        //firebase = new FirebaseClient(GetString(Resource.String.firebase_url)); //not working
        FirebaseDatabase.Instance.GetReference("chats").AddValueEventListener(this);

        fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
        edtChat = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.input);
        lstChat = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.list_of_messages);

        fab.Click += delegate
        {
            PostMessage();
        };

        if (FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser == null)
        {
            StartActivityForResult(new Android.Content.Intent(this, typeof(Signin)), MyResultCode);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email, ToastLength.Short).Show();
            DisplayChatMessage();
        }
    }

private async void PostMessage()
    {
        var items = await firebase.Child("chats").PostAsync(new MessageContent(FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Email, edtChat.Text));
        edtChat.Text = "";
    }

    public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
    {

    }

    public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
    {
        DisplayChatMessage();
    }

    private async void DisplayChatMessage()
    {
        lstMessage.Clear();
        var items = await firebase.Child("chats")
            .OnceAsync<MessageContent>();
        foreach (var item in items)
            lstMessage.Add(item.Object);
        ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, lstMessage);
        lstChat.Adapter = adapter;
    }
```

Comment: did you override the callback when you gave reference this

Comment: I do not remember making a callback to AddValueEventListener(this);, where would the callback be located?

Comment: Ok, were you referring to the async function with the child "chats"? If so, I showed a bit more code so you can look at it.

Comment: I kind of figured it out, I created a 'var options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()' with AppId, ApiKey, DatabaseUrl, and SetStorageBucket. Then I created 'var firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(this, options);' That eliminated illegal argument, but now I get "System.NullReferenceException", no line code, but shows main screen now. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Ok, I fixed the error "System.NullReferenceException" by setting new FirebaseClient(FirebaseURL);. Honestly, I tried running the app in debug mode and the app never launched, but no errors showed. Then, I updated Visual Studio to the new version 15.5.3 and the app finally ran. But then, I ran it the 2nd time and it does not show up anymore.

Comment: I ended up uninstalling Xamarin and installing it again, and now the app runs everytime.